# Alternative to missing samba_backup

Tags: 14.04, backup, samba4

The packaged `samba-4` install does not include the `samba_backup` utility that normally comes with the source code install.

Is it included in some other package?

Is there an alternative solution that Ubuntu has created?

Do I just need to ignore the packaged install and compile from    source?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Read here about the file samba_backup:

https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Backup_and_Recovery

Comment: To be clear, the suggestion here is to go and download the sources, then grab the script from the location advised on that wiki page.